# How to deal with untrusted CA to enable mutual TLS in Nginx?

Tags: ssl, nginx, certificate, ssl-certificate, client-certificates

I want to verify client certificate in Nginx with the following configuration:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

    server_name www.example.com;
    ssl_certificate server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key server.key;

    ssl_verify_client on;
    ssl_client_certificate ca.crt;
}
```

Here "ca.crt" is a ROOT certificate but it is untrusted. When client requests server I can find error "unable to verify the first certificate" with code 21 in Nginx error log. I have tried to import "ca.crt" to the trust store using `update-ca-trust extract` command to let Redhat system trust "ca.crt" but still does NOT work. How can I achieve client verifying in this situation? Thanks.

Comment: Which version of nginx? Have a look at https://tech.mendix.com/linux/2014/10/29/nginx-certs-sni/ maybe